# Exporting environmental variables bash

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, toggle

I am trying to create a bash script that toggles the output everytime the script is run (for some functionality in polybar). The easiest way in my mind to do this is based on the value of an environmental variable, but it isn't working as expected.

This is the script that I have written to test, assume this script is run by something else,and has access to the env variable.

```
echo $STATE
if [[ $STATE == "public" ]]; then
    echo foo
    export STATE='private'
elif [[ $STATE == "private" ]]; then
    echo bar
    export STATE='public'
fi
echo $STATE
```

My desired output is

```
$ ./test.sh
public
foo
private
$ ./test.sh
private
bar
public
```

but the actual output is

```
$ ./test.sh
public
foo
private
$ ./test.sh
public
foo
private
```

It seems that the `export` call isn't persistent

Comment: It isn't; you can't modify the environment of a process from a child process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script runs as a child of your current shell. Child processes cannot directly modify the environment of their parent. That includes environment variables, the current working directory, how signals are handled, etcetera. A process can only modify its environment and, implicitly, the environment of any processes it starts.

The `export` in your script works fine. But it only modifies the value for that script or any child processes (e.g., other scripts) it spawns. By definition it cannot change the value in its parent process.

Solution 1: Implement the script as a shell function. Since functions run in the context of the current shell they can modify its state including its env vars.

Solution 2: Store the `STATE` value somewhere like a dot file in the user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I didn't know that that's how child-processes worked. Here is the finished script, simple, but I learned something. Thanks! https://gitlab.com/SethGower/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/polybar/ip-ipc.sh